# In C, how to read data from file using x<y (y is the file name)

Tags: c

I have a program which needs to read data from a file but I do not want to give the files name and want to take the data into my command file, like nbody < input ???

The code I have been provided (called nbody.c) is a simplified version of an N-body simulation that illustrates the above theory. The code can be compiled, linked and an executable file called nbody created by using the following command.
                                    gcc –lm nbody.c –o nbody

To run the executable an example data input file called input is provided as a starting point. The serial code can be executed using the following command which takes a few seconds to run to completion.
                          nbody < input

my program is;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int m = 1000;
void simulate(int m, int n, double delt, double eps, double x[], double y[], double z[], 
              int iter, double xn[], double yn[], double zn[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
double x[m], y[m], z[m], xn[m], yn[m], zn[m];
double delt, eps, resultant;
int i, n, iter;

char ch, file_name[25];

FILE *fp, *ofp;
//file_name=argv[0];
//char *mode = "r";

printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n"); //instead of this, i wanted it reads automatically, like taking data from the file and calculate it.

gets(file_name);
fp = fopen(file_name, "r");

rewind(fp);
printf("The contents of %s file are : \n", file_name);

 fscanf(fp,"%d  %lf  %lf", &n, &delt, &eps); 
   printf("n = %d, delta t = %lf and tolerance = %lf \n",n, delt, eps);

   fclose(fp);

//while(ch=fgets(fp)!=EOF){

//printf("enter n, delta t and tolerance\n");
//scanf("%d  %lf  %lf", &n, &delt, &eps);
//printf("%c",ch)


//printf("enter n, delta t and tolerance\n");
//scanf("%d  %lf  %lf", &n, &delt, &eps);



simulate(m, n, delt, eps, x, y, z, iter, xn, yn, zn);
printf("n = %d, delta t = %lf and tolerance = %lf \n",n, delt, eps);
for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
   resultant = sqrt(x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]+z[i]*z[i]);
   printf("%-5.7lf  %-5.7lf  %-5.7lf  %-5.7lf\n", x[i], y[i], z[i], resultant);
   }
return 0;
}


void simulate(int m, int n, double delt, double eps, double x[], double y[], double z[], 
              int iter, double xn[], double yn[], double zn[])
{
/* 
Author C.Ierotheou
Aug 2009
Copyright University of Greenwich
routine to crudely simulate body-body interactions (inefficient method)
*/
double zero = 0.0, one = 1.0, twopi = 6.2831853071795864769252866;
int i, itest, j;
double aux,auy,delt2,delt3,eps2,fx,fy,fz,ftx,fty,ftz,step;

// return if n<5
if (n < 5) return;

//initialization
iter = 0;
delt2 = 0.5*delt*delt;
delt3 = delt2*delt2;
eps2 = eps*eps;

//initial distribution of points
auy = zero;
itest=n+1;
j = n+2;
fx = (double)(n);
x[1] = zero;
y[1] = zero;
z[1] = one;
for (i=2; i <= n; i++) {
   step = (double)(i+i-j)/fx;
   auy = fmod(auy+3.6/sqrt(itest*(one-step*step)),twopi);
   aux = sin(auy);
   x[i] = aux*step;
   y[i] = aux*sin(acos(step));
   z[i] = cos(auy);
   }

// main iteration loop

Mainloop:
   iter=iter+1;
   itest=0;
   for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
      // total sum of force vectors
      fx=zero;
      fy=zero;
      fz=zero;
      for (j=1; j<=n ; j++) {
         if (j != i) {
            aux=pow(x[i]-x[j],2.0)+pow(y[i]-y[j],2.0)+pow(z[i]-z[j],2.0);
            aux=aux*sqrt(aux);
            fx=fx+(x[i]-x[j])/aux;
            fy=fy+(y[i]-y[j])/aux;
            fz=fz+(z[i]-z[j])/aux;
                }
         }
      // tangential component of force
      aux=x[i]*fx+y[i]*fy+z[i]*fz;
      ftx=fx-x[i]*aux;
      fty=fy-y[i]*aux;
      ftz=fz-z[i]*aux;
      aux=ftx*ftx+fty*fty+ftz*ftz;
      if (aux > eps2) {
         itest=1;
         aux=sqrt(one-aux*delt3);
         xn[i]=x[i]*aux+ftx*delt2;
         yn[i]=y[i]*aux+fty*delt2;
         zn[i]=z[i]*aux+ftz*delt2;
             }
      }
   for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
      x[i]=xn[i];
      y[i]=yn[i];
      z[i]=zn[i];
      }
   if (itest == 1) goto Mainloop;
}
```

Comment: When you use the input redirection operator in the command shell, then the file is redirected to the standard input of the program.

Comment: thank you Michael for your interest, but how can I do it? I am new in C and I don't know how to use command shell :(

Comment: Does [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells) help? (I don't really understand what problem you are trying to solve; just guessing)

Comment: Sorry mate, it doesn't work :(

Comment: if you have time, do you want me to send he proper page that I need to solve?

Comment: Actually, I need to use "Redirecting command input (<)" but instead of using "sort" I wanted to use my own command like "x" and make calculation wit the data from the "y".

Comment: @Sami Maybe a [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29), like `x | nbody`, is what you need? (guessing again)

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

> In C, how to read data from file using x

You don't do that in C. That kind of functionality is provided by your shell/console/run time environment.

If you have a program `x` that can read its input from `stdin`, and you have a file `y` that contains the input appropriate for `x`, you use:

```
x < y
```

from the shell.

**Update**

I think I know where your problem might be. You have:

```
char ch, file_name[25];

FILE *fp, *ofp;
//file_name=argv[0];
//char *mode = "r";

printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n"); //instead of this, i wanted it reads automatically, like taking data from the file and calculate it.

gets(file_name);
fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
```

Instead of using `gets` to read the name of your input file, you would like to pass the name of the input file from the command line. I hope I am on the right track on this.

In that case, you need to use:

```
char* file_name = argv[1]; // argv[0] is the program name
                           // argv[1] is the first argument to the program
```

Then, you can just use:

```
x y
```

where `x` is your program and `y` contains the input data needed by `x`.

Comment: thank you Sahu for your interest, but how can I do it? I am new in C and I don't know how to use shell :(

Comment: @user3784061, Take a look at http://www.mochima.com/tutorials/getting_started_with_c++.html. Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, I need to use "Redirecting command input (<)" but instead of using "sort" I wanted to use my own command like "x" and make calculation wit the data from the "y".

Comment: Thank you for your time Sahu, but I couldn't use it mate, it gives segmentation fault :( if you have time, do you want me to send the proper page that I need to solve? you could give an idea ;)

Comment: @Sami, it'll be better if you post the updated code and point out where you are seeing segmentation fault. Don't overwrite the original code. Just add the updated code at the end of your original post.

Answer (score 0):

That's some really terrible code. But if you must use it, try changing `main` to this:

```
int main()
{
  double x[m], y[m], z[m], xn[m], yn[m], zn[m];
  double delt, eps, resultant;
  int i, n, iter;

  printf("The contents of %s file are : \n", file_name);

  while (scanf("%d  %lf  %lf", &n, &delt, &eps) == 3)
    printf("n = %d, delta t = %lf and tolerance = %lf \n",n, delt, eps);

  simulate(m, n, delt, eps, x, y, z, iter, xn, yn, zn);
  printf("n = %d, delta t = %lf and tolerance = %lf \n",n, delt, eps);
  for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
    resultant = sqrt(x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]+z[i]*z[i]);
    printf("%-5.7lf  %-5.7lf  %-5.7lf  %-5.7lf\n", x[i], y[i], z[i], resultant);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3784061 The first code I posted was not quite right. Try this.

Comment: that's worst than mine mate, anyway, thanks for the interest ;)

Comment: Actually, I need to use "Redirecting command input (<)" but instead of using "sort" I wanted to use my own command like "x" and make calculation wit the data from the "y".